# Parse JSON with Swift 3 XCode 8

Tags: php, json, swift

I have an app that allows you to enter in data and it posts it to a server running mysql I created. I then wrote the PHP file to translate mysql to JSON so that my app could list the contents in a table. However it is not working, I get errors saying "Invalid value around character 0" or "JSON text did not start with array or object". All I want to do is get the data and convert it to an index so that I can display certain data throughout my app.

php code:

```
//including the file dboperation
require_once '../includes/DbOperation2.php';

//creating a response array to store data
$response = array();

//creating a key in the response array to insert values
//this key will store an array iteself
$response['profile'] = array();

//creating object of class DbOperation
$db = new DbOperation();

//getting the teams using the function we created
$profile = $db->getAllUsers();

//looping through all the teams.
//creating a temporary array
$temp = array();

//inserting the team in the temporary array
$temp['id'] = $profiles['id'];
$temp['displayName']=$profiles['displayName'];
$temp['department']=$profiles['department'];
$temp['mamager']=$profiles['mamager'];
$temp['office']=$profiles['office'];
$temp['util']=$profiles['util'];

//inserting the temporary array inside response
array_push($response['profile'],$temp);
}

//displaying the array in json format
echo json_encode($response);
```

Output looks like this:

```
{"profile":[{"id":1,"displayName":"Jacob Blacksten","department":"DF","mamager":"San","office":"NYC","util":2},{"id":2,"displayName":"John Smith","department":"SS","mamager":"Jack","office":"Boston","util":3}]}
```

xcode:

```
   guard let url = URL(string: "http://ipAddress/MyWebService/api/getteams.php") else { return}

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {
            print(data)
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Please some one help me with the xcode. I need to first get it to parse and once parsed I would like to put them in an array and index them. I know this might be a duplicate question but I have spent days looking for this answer and I don't know coding enough to understand everything.

Comment: Try to tag more narrowly than this. I don't see anything MySQL related at all and Xcode isn't directly relevant. If the problem is in your PHP code, verify that the output from that server-side component is correct before expecting your Swift code to work.

Comment: You're right the MySQL tag was incorrect. Above you will see the output given to me by the server. It is exactly how all the articles I have read have it. To me I am missing something in xcode but I don't know what.

Comment: Where does this error come from? When you debug your Swift code are you getting the right JSON string in `data`?

Comment: The error is thrown right at the "let json = try" line and I am not seeing the data it is suppose to be passing in at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can parse this. This is how I would do it.

First, create an `NSObject` class of the keys you will be parsing.

```
class DataObject: NSObject { var Name: String? var ID: String?

}
```

In your ViewController class (Or wherever you have your method to retrieve data), create a global variable of type DataObject

```
var dataObject = [DataObject]()

func retrieveData(dataToParse: [String : Any]) {

//dataToParse will be your json variable and cast it as a dictionary of [String : Any]

let object = DataObject()
object.setValuesForKey(dataToParse)
dataObject.append(object)

}
```

Now you can access your data just like an array, kinda.

```
let name = dataObject[0].Name
```